# cocos2d v2.0 upgrade & RootViewController

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently upgrading my cocos2d app from 0.99 to 2.0. The app uses ZBarSDK for QR code scanning and the integration was done like that:

```
// present and release the controller
[[RootViewController sharedInstance] presentModalViewController: reader animated: YES];
```

However that doesn't work with the new version of cocos2d. What should I change to make it work with cocos2d 2.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[app.navController presentModalViewController: reader animated:YES];
```